# How to make query based on string length on aggregate function mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have product collections like this:

```
{
  _id: 'prod_id_1',
  type: SIMPLE,
  name: 'Product Simple 1',
  barcode: '00000004'
},
{
  _id: 'prod_id_2',
  type: SIMPLE,
  name: 'Product Simple 2',
  barcode: '00000005'
},
{
  _id: 'prod_id_3',
  type: VARIED,
  name: 'Product Varied 1',
  variants: [
     {
       id: 'variant_aqua_base_m_size', 
       name: 'Variant AquaM', 
       barcode: '121200000005'
     },
     {
       id: 'variant_aqua_base_m_size', 
       name: 'Variant AquaM', 
       barcode: '00000007'
     }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 'prod_id_4',
  type: SIMPLE,
  name: 'Product Simple 4',
  barcode: '121200000008'
}
```

I want to display all product that has barcode length 8. If only product simple, I can use $where, example:

```
db.product.find({$where: "this.barCode.length == 8", 'barCode': {$exists: true}})
```

If I want to display product varied, I have to $unwind the variants. But, I have not find operator like $where in aggregate function. Any ide what operator should I use to find barcode based on string length ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have the answer.

```
db.product.aggregate([
{"$project":{ 
         "u_barCode": {
             "$let": {
                 "vars": {
                     "variantBarCode": {
                         "$cond": [
                             {"$eq": ["$variants", null]},
                             [], 
                             {"$ifNull": ["$variants.barCode", [null]]}
                         ]
                     }, 
                     "barCode": {"$ifNull": ["$barCode", null]}
                 }, 
                 "in": {
                     "$cond": [ 
                         {"$eq": ["$$variantBarCode", [null]]}, 
                         {"$map": {
                             "input": {"$literal": [null]}, 
                             "as": "el", 
                             "in": "$$barCode"
                         }}, 
                         "$$variantBarCode"
                     ]
                 }
             }
         },
        "type" : "$type"
     }
 },
 {$unwind : "$u_barCode"},
 {$match: {u_barCode: {$regex: '^[0-9]{8}$', $options: 'm'}}},
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe you can use a `OR` condition like

```
db.product.find({"$or": [{"barCode.length == 8"}, {"variants.barCode.length == 8"}], 'barCode': {$exists: true}})
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, but It won't work, I have tested it. $or operator must have one or more expression. '{"barCode.length == 8"}'  is not expresion.